# jade, use if statement to decide whether read some code

Tags: pug

I want to use Jade to decide whether read some code.

I seperate my jade file in a index file, and then include other needed file.

**index.jade**

```
body
    include header
    block main
    include footer
```

I will extend the block main in other jade file.

My prblem is I want to reuse this index file.
However, in some case, I hope it will not include the footer.
Thus, I think I can use `if..else` to do that.

I want to ask does the `if..else` help me to judge the extends file name?

For example:

```
if it is not no_footer.jade
    include footer
```

I am not sure whether jade has this function.

If the jade can't help me do that, very sorry for this stupid question.

But I really need your help! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask does the `if..else` help me to judge the extends file name?

No, you cannot do this withJade.

But you can solve the problem by including a file where you wrap the content of it into a block 
and in your jade file which should not show the content you can overwrite the block with no content

**footer.jade**

```
block footer
  span copyright 2014
```

**page_without_footer.jade**

```
extends index
block main
  p lorem ipsum

//- overwrite the footer with nothing / delete the block
block footer
```

Comment: Very thank you! I never think of this method. It really help me!